# Is there any common PHP classes for converting SQL results set's into a json

Tags: php, sql, json

Im using [D3](http://d3js.org/) to make some charts

Manually forming a json for each query seems a bit counter intuitive

Is there a better way to do this?

Or is it to make a json php script for each chart and try to get my data to fit or can I get a generic php script to configure the outputted json from sql?

Comment: What do you mean by 'manually forming'? Is json_encode() not sufficient for what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Pull out all the records as objects or arrays and `json_encode` them?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php > PDO::FETCH_ASSOC + http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php ?

Comment: I am aware of json_encode() and of putting them in objects and arrays - but my question is - do I have to do this for each dataset or chart? - eg. if you use Excel to make a chart, a two column dataset works with lots of diffrent charts - I was wondering if there was a generic constructor to create jsons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's so hard about it?

```
$sql = "SELECT field1, field2, field3, ....";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);  // <--- was that so hard?
```

Comment: Yes that is easy but what if my chart is expecting the json in a particular format?

Comment: how would a common class be able to handle uncommon formats? You can encode arbitary data structures - build your complicated format as a standard php array, nested-array, mixed array/object, etc... json_encode() will take it all.

Comment: +1 I think you have answered my question - thanks. I’m looking to have pre-defined SQL to get the data, then if I setup a json creator for each chart - so long as my data is retrieved in the correct format my chart will work. I think what I need to do is have a json creator for the charts that I know that json works with and have SQL stored that work with that particular json - if that makes sense - so basically standardisation throughout

Comment: json_encode **is** the creator. you don't build json manually. you build a NATIVE structure, then use json_encode to convert from native->json. json is the very last thing you do before sending things on to the client. think of it as more of a transport format.

Comment: Got it - thanks Marc! of course your right -I will get some native structures sorted first.

Comment: @MarcB: please, don't answer questions by using `mysql_*` extension functions... the extension has (finally) begun the deprecation process. It's down to us to spread the word, so that the soft deprecation can be sped up

Comment: @elias: it got deprecated in 5.4, and given the amount of code out there that uses the library, it's NOT going to vanish in 5.5 or whatever. it'll wait until 6.0 or 7.0. look at how long it took to finally turn off magic_quotes and all other other stupidities.

Comment: Im using PDO - but the example is enough to give me the idea I have found http://nitschinger.at/Handling-JSON-like-a-boss-in-PHP - I just need to work out how to format my data in a PHP object or array

Comment: @MarcB: the [deprecation was announced over a year ago](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799), and yes it will take a while before they actually start issuing the `E_DEPRECATED` warnings and stuff, but the more people know about it now, the faster the extension can be deprecated. Every bit helps, is all I'm saying

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: fine, but then just to be fair, you should go equally hard on people who are still using `if(magic_quotes_gpc()) { stripslashes(...) }`.

Comment: @MarcB: I do, don't worry... :P

Answer (score 2):

Verry simple, just `json_encode` the result array using a function.

```
header('Content-type: application/json'); //for cooperation with D3

function getJsonChartResults($tablename,$columns = Array())
{
    $fields = count($columns) == 0 ? "*" : implode(",", $columns);
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.DATABASE_HOST.';dbname='.DATABASE_NAME, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD);
    $results = $dbh->query("SELECT ".$fields." FROM ".$tablename);
    $dbh = null;
    return json_encode($results);
}

echo getJsonChartResults("Results"); //Get data for all collumns
echo getJsonChartResults("Results",Array("id","key","value")); //Get data for specified collumns
```